# Layout issue on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee, awt, guice

Please help I couldn't find any answer about my issue after googling so many times.
I'm developing an gui app in which I have a JFrame with some MenuItem(Add User,All User) with a Border Layout and I'm opening a custom JPanel (AllUsers) which will open on All Users click from mainFrame and I have successfully doing this, but my problem is Layout which I was using on Jpanel to place the component on it, If I use Absolute layout my Jpanel will show that Component but if I use another Layout except Absolute on my AllUsers Jpanel then no any component has seen on it.
please tell me what is the problem behind this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it necessary to install mysql database and define url for every
>   client system to run my jar

The depends on your application architecture.  Would you like the clients to connect to a common database server?  If so, then they can share a common JDBC URL and a single MySQL installation, which will need to be modified to use the server hostname, e.g. `jdbc:mysql://dbserver:3306/SRT`.

Comment: my database is not on server it is locally installed on client end